# Faster-RCNN Evaluation

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am training a Faster-RCNN(VGG-16 architecture) on INRIA Person dataset. I was trained for 180,000 training steps. But when I evaluate the network, it gives varying result with the same image.
Following are the images [image: First Evaluation]

[image: Second Evaluation]

[image: Third Evaluation]

I am not sure why does it give different results for the same set of weights.The network is implemented in caffe.
Any insight into the problem is much appreciated.

Following image shows different network losses
[image]

Comment: what have you changed to get the three different results on the same image? have you changed NMS parameters? input scale?

Comment: Nothing, it's all exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently, I also prepared my own dataset to training, and got the similar results as yours.

The following is my experiences and share with you:

1. Check input format include images and your bounding box csvfile or xml (where always put on Annotation file) whether all bounding box (x1, y1, x2, y2) correct?
2. Then check roidb/imdb loading python script (put on FasterRCNN/lib/datasets/pascal_roi.py, and maybe yours is inria.py),
   make sure _load_xxx_annotation() correctly loaded all bounding box by print bounding_box and filename. **Importantly**, if your script is copied and modified the pascal_roi.py or any prototype script, please check whether it will saved all roi and image info into cache file, if yes you need to delete that cache file when you change any configure files and re-try.
3. Finally, make sure that all bounding box correctly generating when network is training (e.g. print **minibatch** variable to show filename and corresponding x1, y1, x2, y2 shown at FasterRCNN/lib/roi_data_layer/layer.py). If roi generator generate correctly, the bounding box will not differ with your manually select bounding box largely.

Some similar [issue](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/issues/65) may cause this problem as well.